# Click() action is not working with firefox in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

1. Below code not working for click action.
2. I have tried it on chrome but not working on Firefox.

   ```
       package SeleniumCase;
       import org.openqa.selenium.By;
       import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
       import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
       import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

       public class SeleniumClass {
       public static void main(String[] args) 

        {

          WebDriver driver;
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\Librar\\geckodriver.exe");
          driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("my company url hide for security reason");
          driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("admin@school.com");
          driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
          driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("passw0rd");
          driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();         
        } 
   }
   ```

Comment: Try this code, it's in C# `IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
                js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error?Please share the exception or error

try this

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            js.executeScript("var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" + "evt.initMouseEvent('click',true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0,null);" + "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evt);",  webElement);
```